# How to subset raster image using gdal?

Tags: image, visual-c++, raster, gdal, qgis

I have read pixel values of an raster image using GDAL libraries in visual studio 2010(vc++).
Next is , I have to crop the image (subset) according to the grid given in shape file.
Forget about the grid this time. 
I just want to clip square or rectangular area and save to new file.
I have read some documents which suggest about gdal_translate and gdal_warp function to use but it can only be run in python where as i want to use c++.
Please help me as early as possible.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45509/how-to-subset-raster-image-using-gdal.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem of cropping the image using VC++ with gdal libraries. I have created VRTDataset of my desired size of raster to be cropped and then save it using CreateCopy().